# C# - Limiting scope to ternary statement

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

EDIT: Originally, this post's example had dealt with hash codes, so you will see some comments using param.GetHashCode(), rather than (1+param). To get more to the point, I have changed the functions to calculate one plus the absolute value of some number.

Let's say that I want to create a function that calculates the absolute value of some integer (without using Math.Abs). I could write something similar to:

```
int absoluteValueOfOnePlus(int param)
{
    int onePlusParam= 1 + param;
    return ((onePlusParam> 0) ? (onePlusParam) : (-onePlusParam) );
}
```

I'm looking to limit the scope of onePlusParm to within the ternary statement--something similar to:

```
int absoluteValueOfOnePlus(intparam)
{
    return (((int onePlusParam = 1 + param) > 0) ? (onePlusParam) : (-onePlusParam) );
}
```

I understand that this is not valid C#, but it proves a good example for what I'm trying to perform--create some variable which exists only in the scope of a ternary operator.

Comment: "I'm looking to compress this method down to one line". Can you explain the reason why you need to do this?

Comment: you could do `int i; return i = param.GetHashCode() > 0 ? i : -i;` ... I wouldn't but you could.

Comment: @openshac, it's more about limiting scope than anything else. If the function were much larger, i would exist throughout the rest of the function. Using a declaration within the ternary statement would limit the scope to within the ternary--after the statement completes, i is deleted.

Comment: @MatthewWhited, that's not much better. My goal is to limit the scope of i. Moving the calculation into the ternary statement still leaves i within the scope of the function, rather than the ternary statement.

Comment: you can just create a block of scope with `{ ... }`.  Anything inside of the block will be out of scope outside of the block.

Comment: How about this for one line... `return Math.Abs(param.GetHashCode());`

Comment: @MatthewWhited, what I wrote was more an example than anything else--I had mentioned that I was aware that Math.Abs would provide a simpler solution. I was unaware of the scope block within C#, so that should prove to be a viable solution.

Answer (score 3):

The parts of a ternary expression are expressions. If the language designers were to allow what you're asking for, they would probably do it for all expressions rather than just for ternary expressions. You would then also be able to do `if ((int n = foo()) != 0) bar(n);`.

In C#, declarations are statements, not expressions. So the answer is no, you can't do this. However, the `for` statement can take a declaration, so the closest you can get to a single statement is this:

```
for (int i = param.GetHashCode();;)
    return (i > 0) ? i : -i;
```

which is technically a single statement, albeit a compound one, and on two lines. But that looks awful code and I wouldn't write it like that.

If your main concern is minimizing the scope of `i`, then use a small scope for it:

```
int positiveHash(string param)
{
    // Some statements here...
    // ...

    // Start a small scope
    {
        int i = param.GetHashCode();
        if (...)
            return ((i > 0) ? (i) : (-i) );
    }

    // Some more C# statements here.
    // i is out of scope here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The goal of my question was limiting the scope of i--not necessarily clean code, so this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply write:

```
int GetPositiveHash(string param)
{
    return Math.Abs(param.GetHashCode());
}
```

or

```
int GetPositiveHash(string param)
{
    int hashCode = param.GetHashCode();

    return Math.Abs(hashCode);
}
```

The aids readability, maintainability and more importantly in this case avoid [premature optimization which is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

If you are really worried about performance then profile you code and see where your biggest bottlenecks are. I'd be surprised if `GetPosiitiveHash()` is causing the biggest bottleneck.

You might like to have a look at the [.Net Framework source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,0a17bbac4851d0d4) for `String.GetHashCode()`.  You'll see that a ternary operator is going to have quite a minimal saving compared what going on inside the `GetHashCode()` method.

It's worth remembering:

> The full version of the quote is "We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil." and I agree with this. Its usually not worth
>   spending a lot of time micro-optimizing code before its obvious where
>   the performance bottlenecks are.

from [The fallacy of premature optimization](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451)

Comment: The concept I gave was more an example than anything else. I was exploring limiting a variable's scope to within the ternary statement--not necessarily optimization of the exact code block I provided. That being said, that's definitely a quote worth remembering.

Comment: OK, might be worth modifiying your question to replace the GetHashCode() with something trivial, it's obscures the optimization you are trying to acheive.

Comment: It maybe easier to add an update section to the bottom of your original post so that the existing replies don't become obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

You could substitute having a data variable (`i`) in scope to having a function variable in scope. The advantage is a function is more likely to be written only once and not likely to be misused.

```
int positiveHash(string param)
{
    Func<int, int> absoluteValue = i => (i > 0) ? i : -1;

    return absoluteValue(param.GetHashCode());
}
```

Comment: My experience with lambda expressions is limited, but I like this. I'll look more into function variables--thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Besides just creating a new block you could also use the built in Absolute value function `Math.Abs(...)` or define your own lambda/function;

...built in ...

```
public static int hash(string param)
{
    return Math.Abs(param.GetHashCode());
}
```

... lambda ...

```
static Func<int, int> abs = i => i > 0 ? i : -i;
public static int hash(string param)
{
    return abs(param.GetHashCode());
}
```

... static function ...

```
static int Abs(int i)
{
    return i > 0 ? i : -i;
}
public static int hash(string param)
{
    return Abs(param.GetHashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And my attempt

```
static int positiveHash(string param)
{
     return new List<string>() {param}.Select(s => s.GetHashCode()).Select(i => (i > 0) ? (i) : (-i)).Single();
}
```

(Of course your code (and mine) is bad,you need to split your method into 2 smaller ones)

and the updated question

```
static int absoluteValueOfOnePlus(int intparam)
{
        return new List<int> { intparam }.Select(n => n + 1).Select(i => (i > 0) ? (i) : (-i)).Single();
}
```